# Flutter: looping dropdown not showing selected value

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, dropdown, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making a for loop to repeat a widget which has a dropdown menu inside. However, when it is not showing the selected value when I click. Anyone has looped a dropdown button before?
This is the code I have so far. It is placed inside a for loop.

```
child: new DropdownButton(

                value: _relationSelects[i],
                hint: Text("Select Category"),
                items: _relationschoice.map((String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                  child: new Text(value.toString()),
                );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _relationSelects[i] = value;      // Problem here too, the element doesn’t show in the dropdown as selected
                    print("Selected: ${_relationSelects[i]} (${i})");
                  });
                },


              ),
```

It is able to print the selected value. but it's not changing state.

If i use a String for the value instead of a List-String , it can show the same selected value for all looped dropdown, which is not correct.

I have checked this answer before but it is still not working
[Can't show the dropdown selected value in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046592/cant-show-the-dropdown-selected-value-in-flutter)

May anyone please advise? Thank you.